# How do I pass data from one sibling to another using React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a search bar with a submit button that fetches data from an API, all located in a fixed Nav bar. Every time I click submit, I would like React Router to change to a results page, and display the results.

I can't seem to figure out how to pass the data, either as props or as state to this new component. Here is my search API code:

```
const Search = () => {
  const apiKey = 'xxxxxx';
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    searchAPI();
  };

  const searchAPI = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${apiKey}&s=${input}`);
    const data = await res.json();
    setItems(data.Search);
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <input onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
      <Link to={{ pathname: '/results', state: items }}>
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          search
        </button>
      </Link>
    </form>
  );
};
```

And here is the code in my results component:

```
const SearchResults = () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>RESULTS</h1>
      {results.map((result) => {
        return <li key={results.Search.imdbID}>{result.Search.Title}</li>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

How would I go about getting the data from `items` in my search API component into `results` in my results component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close. You could use `useLocation` hook from "react-router-dom" in your SearchResults component like so

```
const { state } = useLocation();
```

Items that you pass from the Link would be there.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<Link to="results" myData={{ state: items }}>
```

In results components you can access params:

```
import {useRouteMatch} from 'react-router-dom'
const {params} = useRouteMatch();

console.log(params.myData);
```